# mountしたISOイメージに含まれるファイルの権限を変更したい

Tags: linux

ISOファイルを以下のコマンドでmountしました。(Redhat7.4)

```
mount -o loop xxxx.iso /mnt
```

mount先にファイルがあるのですがリードオンリーとなっていました。

```
chmod 777 ファイル
```

上記コマンドを実行したのですが、mount先だからか反映されませんでした。
mount先のファイルを "読み書き可能" にする方法はありますか？

Comment: 質問と直接の関係はありませんが、余談として。単に「Redhat」と書くと、[とても古いバージョンのOS](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) を指すことになります。現在用いられているのは「 **RHEL** (Red Hat **Enterprise** Linux)」と呼ばれるOSかと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISOファイルは常に読み取り専用でマウントされます。アクセス権限を変更したいファイルが有る場合には、別のディレクトリにコピーしてから `chmod` 等を実行してください。

また、必要であれば変更を加えたディレクトリを元に新しいISOファイルを `mkisofs` で生成することも可能です。

**参考:**
[Unable to mount ISO in write mode - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/390610)